# Changing IIS app id

Tags: iis-7

I might have to change the IDs of the web apps in a Windows Server 2008 server running IIS 7.

Is that recommended? Should I stay away from it? If it is ok for me to do it, what should I watch for? Logs, possible errors, etc?

Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you make sure that you don't have any duplicate Id's you'll be good.

When you do change it, the sites will stop because they will momentarily appear to be duplicates, but once you start them, they will work perfectly.

The numbers don't need to be incrementing so it's fine to have gaps.  Just make sure that it's a uint.

Comment: will my log directory change as a result of the change?

Comment: It won't change it, but new logs will write to the new location, so it would make sense to rename the log folders at the same time.